# Confluent hyper-geometric function

Tags: hypergeometric-function

Is there any identity in the confluent hypergeometric function that connects the following?
${}_1{F_1}\left( {a + n + 1,b + n + 1, - c} \right)$ and
${}_1{F_1}\left( {a + 1,b + 1, - c} \right)$ where a, b and c are positive real numbers

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\;{}_1F_1(a,b,x) = \frac{a}{b}\;{}_1F_1(a+1,b+1,x)
$$
Apply this inductively to get
$$
\frac{d^n}{dc^n}\;{}_1F_1(a+1,b+1,-c) =
(-1)^n\;\frac{(a+1)(a+2)\cdots(a+n)}{(b+1)(b+2)\cdots(b+n)}
{}_1F_1(a+n+1,b+n+1,-c)
$$